# AudioWorklet - Set output to Float32Array to stream live audio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio-streaming, web-audio-api, audio-processing

I have audio data streaming from the server to the client. It starts as a Node.js buffer (which is a Uint8Array) and is then sent to the AudioWorkletProcessor via port.postMessage(), where it is converted into a Float32Array and stored in this.data. I have spent hours trying to set the output to the audio data contained in the Float32Array. Logging the Float32Array pre-processing shows accurate data, but logging it during processing shows that it is not changing when the new message is posted. This is probably a gap in my low-level audio-programming knowledge.

When data arrives in the client, the following function is called:

```
  process = (data) => {
        this.node.port.postMessage(data)
  }
```

As an aside, (and you can let me know) maybe I should be using parameter descriptors instead of postMessage? Anyways, here's my AudioWorkletProcessor:

```
class BypassProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.isPlaying = true;
    this.port.onmessage = this.onmessage.bind(this)
  }

  static get parameterDescriptors() {
    return [{ // Maybe we should use parameters. This is not utilized at present.
      name: 'stream',
      defaultValue: 0.707
    }];
  }

  convertBlock = (incomingData) => { // incoming data is a UInt8Array
    let i, l = incomingData.length;
    let outputData = new Float32Array(incomingData.length);
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      outputData[i] = (incomingData[i] - 128) / 128.0;
    }
    return outputData;
  }

  onmessage(event) {
    const { data } = event;
    let ui8 = new Uint8Array(data);
    this.data = this.convertBlock(ui8)
  }

  process(inputs, outputs) {
    const input = inputs[0];
    const output = outputs[0];
    if (this.data) {
      for (let channel = 0; channel < output.length; ++channel) {
        const inputChannel = input[channel]
        const outputChannel = output[channel]
        for (let i = 0; i < inputChannel.length; ++i) {
          outputChannel[i] = this.data[i]
        }
      }
    }

    return true;

  }
}

registerProcessor('bypass-processor', BypassProcessor);
```

How can I simply set the output of the AudioWorkletProcessor to the data coming through?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, did you get it ?

Comment: @vmontanheiro No, unfortunately. I am able to do it without the AudioWorklet however

Comment: I got it! Are you getting your data from an RTP packet comming from server ?? And are you posting message to your process using SharedArrayBuffer? Don't lose your hope. haha

Comment: Omg! if there's any way I could pick your brain on the SharedArrayBuffer pattern, do get in touch! Currently just have a pretty vanilla pattern with packets being sent from the server

Comment: SharedArrayBuffer is the preferred way because it doesn't generate additional garbage, but I think that your problem is the same that mine. My data length is 160 bytes, but the AudioWorkletProcessor process only each 128 bytes, so I'm trying managing it a BufferRing(FIFO) to return the buffer with a corrct size. When I finish I'll share it with you.

Comment: @vmontanheiro 

Comment: I'm coding with base in this example : https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/web-audio-samples/tree/master/audio-worklet/design-pattern/wasm-ring-buffer
I have it working with my input data comming from microphone to my server, now I need a reverse solution.

Answer (score 5):

The AudioWorkletProcessor process only each 128 bytes, so you need to manage your own buffers to make sure that is the case for an `AudioWorklet`, probably by adding a FIFO. 
I resolved something like this using a RingBuffer(FIFO) implemented in WebAssembly, in my case I was receiving a buffer with 160 bytes.

Look my AudioWorkletProcessor implementation

```
import Module from './buffer-kernel.wasmodule.js';
import { HeapAudioBuffer, RingBuffer, ALAW_TO_LINEAR } from './audio-helper.js';

class SpeakerWorkletProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  constructor(options) {
    super();
    this.payload = null;
    this.bufferSize = options.processorOptions.bufferSize; // Getting buffer size from options
    this.channelCount = options.processorOptions.channelCount;
    this.inputRingBuffer = new RingBuffer(this.bufferSize, this.channelCount);
    this.outputRingBuffer = new RingBuffer(this.bufferSize, this.channelCount);
    this.heapInputBuffer = new HeapAudioBuffer(Module, this.bufferSize, this.channelCount);
    this.heapOutputBuffer = new HeapAudioBuffer(Module, this.bufferSize, this.channelCount);
    this.kernel = new Module.VariableBufferKernel(this.bufferSize);
    this.port.onmessage = this.onmessage.bind(this);
  }

  alawToLinear(incomingData) {
    const outputData = new Float32Array(incomingData.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < incomingData.length; i++) {
      outputData[i] = (ALAW_TO_LINEAR[incomingData[i]] * 1.0) / 32768;
    }
    return outputData;
  }

  onmessage(event) {
    const { data } = event;
    if (data) {
      this.payload = this.alawToLinear(new Uint8Array(data)); //Receiving data from my Socket listener and in my case converting PCM alaw to linear
    } else {
      this.payload = null;
    }
  }

  process(inputs, outputs) {
    const output = outputs[0];
    if (this.payload) {
      this.inputRingBuffer.push([this.payload]); // Pushing data from my Socket

      if (this.inputRingBuffer.framesAvailable >= this.bufferSize) { // if the input data size hits the buffer size, so I can "outputted"  
        this.inputRingBuffer.pull(this.heapInputBuffer.getChannelData());
        this.kernel.process(
          this.heapInputBuffer.getHeapAddress(),
          this.heapOutputBuffer.getHeapAddress(),
          this.channelCount,
        );
        this.outputRingBuffer.push(this.heapOutputBuffer.getChannelData());
      }
      this.outputRingBuffer.pull(output); // Retriving data from FIFO and putting our output
    }
    return true;
  }
}

registerProcessor(`speaker-worklet-processor`, SpeakerWorkletProcessor);
```

Look the AudioContext and AudioWorklet instances

```
 this.audioContext = new AudioContext({
      latencyHint: 'interactive',
      sampleRate: this.sampleRate,
      sinkId: audioinput || "default"
    });

    this.audioBuffer = this.audioContext.createBuffer(1, this.audioSize, this.sampleRate);
    this.audioSource = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
    this.audioSource.buffer = this.audioBuffer;
    this.audioSource.loop = true;
    this.audioContext.audioWorklet
    .addModule('workers/speaker-worklet-processor.js')
    .then(() => {
      this.speakerWorklet = new AudioWorkletNode(
        this.audioContext,
        'speaker-worklet-processor',
        {
          channelCount: 1,
          processorOptions: {
            bufferSize: 160, //Here I'm passing the size of my output, I'm just saying to RingBuffer what size I need 
            channelCount: 1,
          },
        },
      );
      this.audioSource.connect(this.speakerWorklet).connect(this.audioContext.destination);
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log("Receiver ", err);
    })
```

Look how I'm receiving and sending the data from Socket to audioWorklet

```
  protected onMessage(e: any): void { //My Socket message listener
    const { data:serverData } = e;
    const socketId = e.socketId;
    if (this.audioWalking && this.ws && !this.ws.isPaused() && this.ws.info.socketId === socketId) {
      const buffer = arrayBufferToBuffer(serverData);
      const rtp = RTPParser.parseRtpPacket(buffer);
      const sharedPayload = new Uint8Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(rtp.payload.length)); //sharing javascript buffer memory between main thread and worklet thread
      sharedPayload.set(rtp.payload, 0);
      this.speakerWorklet.port.postMessage(sharedPayload); //Sending data to worklet
    }
  }
```

For help people I putted on Github the piece important of this solution

- [audio-worklet-processor-wasm-example](https://github.com/vmontanheiro/audio-worklet-processor-wasm-example)

I followed this example, it have the all explanation how the RingBuffer works

- [wasm-ring-buffer](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/web-audio-samples/tree/master/audio-worklet/design-pattern/wasm-ring-buffer)

Comment: Excellent work, and thank you for putting together this answer!

Comment: Will study this and see if I can apply to my use case. While not using RTP (webRTC), I still think it applies.

Comment: You're welcome!! You'll shiver, the audio output absolutely in real time, without any latency. I'm not using webRTC, I'm using a UDP socket  and handling my own RTP header.  Good lucky :D

Comment: Hey, do you know how can I use AudioWorklet with GainNode? I need to control the volume now.

Comment: I think Google's articles on introducing the AudioWorklet have good examples of using parameter descriptors to accomplish things like that. I'm on a phone so I'll try and post links when I get the chance